# "IOError No such file or directory" for an image file that IS in the current directory

Tags: python, tkinter, notepad++, python-imaging-library, python-2.7

I'm using Python Imaging Library and Tkinter.
I am currently trying to display an image as a label, and I'm getting the above exception.
My 35 line source:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Label")

        self.img = Image.open("diesl.jpg")
        diesl = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        label = Label(self, image=diesl)

        label.image = diesl
        label.pack()

        self.pack()

    def setGeometry(self):
        w, h = self.img.size
        self.parent.geometry(("%dx%d+300+300") % (w, h))

def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    ex.setGeometry()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How do you know that it's actually in the current directory, and not in some other directory that you only *think* is the current directory?

Comment: Try this code: f=open("diesl.jpg") and if it is not working there is a matter of permission.

Comment: @lc2817: Permissions give a different `IOError` value.

Comment: OK in that case you are right he has not got the file in the same directory.

Comment: I've triple-checked. I definitely have it in the same directory.

Comment: @Uk4Life. What does "same directory" mean? The current directory is not necessarily the same as the directory that the script is in.

Comment: Okay, this is strange. When I run the program by its shell association (ie. through cmd or by double-clicking the script's icon) it runs just fine. I'm only getting the exception when I run it through Notepad++.

Comment: Maybe because notepad++ behaves a different way (copying the file somewhere else or executing it in another directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are right in your comment: Notepad++ seems to launch the files from its own directory.

You can find the solution to your problem here: http://damienlearnsperl.blogspot.com/2009/01/launch-your-perl-script-from-notepad.html (check Lee's comment) if you still intend to use Notepad ++

Comment: I didn't realize that npp used its own directory as the working directory. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact code and it worked perfectly.

Me thinks you're in a strange directory
(such as Program Files which requires special permissions)

Why don't you try ending explorer.exe through task manager,
than running your code again?

Comment: As said before it is certainly not a matter of permission otherwise it would be said in the error.

Comment: Probably, but you never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to Python but my method works for me.
Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
import platform
import webbrowser

sys = platform.system()


def setup_window():
    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("300x150")
    window.title("Computer Utility GUI")


def style_window():
    path = "/home/pi/Desktop/tool icon"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label = Label(window, image = img)
    label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

setup_window()
style_window()

window.mainloop()
```

How I got it to work:

1) (You need to import os but in my code I'd already done that.) From the resultant shell window when running my code I typed
os.getcwd()

This gives you the current working directory.

2) Make sure your file is saved in this Directory; with your Python script.

3)Type the running directory into the parentheses of wherever you need to use it then place a slash at the end and wait.

4) A little Widget should appear using the arrow keys go down and find the image that should be saved in the path.
Then when selecting it press enter and that is the path you need to use,

5) Hopefully it should work. I found Python didn't require the ending.